# Elliptic curves over extensions of 64-bit fields

Tags: elliptic-curves

Are there any standard (or at least well-know) elliptic curves over $F_{p^4}$ where $p$ is a ~64-bit prime? I know Microsoft has [FourQ curve](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/565) which works over $F_{p^2}$ where $p$ is a 127-bit prime, but I haven't come across any curve that works over extensions of ~64-bit fields.

If there are no standard/well-know curves that fit this, are there any fundamental reasons for why elliptic curves over $F_{p^4}$ would not be a good idea?

Comment: Minor nit: for FourQ, $p$ is a 127 bit prime...

Comment: There is an algorithm running in $\tilde{O}(p^{2-2/n})$, details in [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00337631/document). In your case, $n$ is $4$ so it runs faster than generic methods to solve the discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: So - does this mean that a curve over $F_{p^4}$ would have about 96 bit security level? Also, does this affect FourQ curve in the same way?

Comment: The attack would still be mostly impracticable since it would require a lot of memory. FourQ is over a field $\mathbf F_{p^2}$, and the attack on the paper does not reduce  the security compared to generic algorithms.